# Handling 503 Error in Express/Node.js especially in TryCatch case

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, try-catch, http-status-code-503

I have a special case for which I want to clear the possible reason for 503 Error. The following code snippet has a catch statement which runs when system is not able to find any results

```
app.post('/api/fetch/user', function(req, res){
   var email = req.body.emailTxt;
   db.one('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1', [email])
       .then(function(data){
           console.log('DATA:', data);

           var userCard = { id: data.user_id, name: data.user_name, 
                            email: data.email, regDate: data.date_created };

           res.status(200).json({ 'valid': true, '_payload': userCard });
       })
       .catch(function(error){
           if(error.search(/No data returned from the query/im) > 0)    // regex case insensitive search and search multiline as source string is multiline
              res.status(500).send('Invalid Request Match');
           else 
              res.status(500).send('ERROR: '+error);
       })
```

`});`

When my API call is made to this API end point and when no result found the control moves in `catch()` which is fine but quite strangely it returns `503 - Request timeout` error.
I have tried to to remove conditions in `if()` in order to debug but seems like no matter what but the `if-else` does not seem working in ExpressJs. 

Note: Everything works well and also when control stays in `.then()`. If I remove `if,else` and keep simple error display/response return then everything works ok. There is nothing special included in my API; it is only one single page script I prepared to test API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got error in the `.catch` block.

Try to modify the code and see if this helps:

```
app.post('/api/fetch/user', function(req, res){
     var email = req.body.emailTxt;
     db.one('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1', [email])
         .then(function(data){
             console.log('DATA:', data);

             var userCard = { id: data.user_id, name: data.user_name, 
                              email: data.email, regDate: data.date_created };

             res.status(200).json({ 'valid': true, '_payload': userCard });
         })
         .catch(function(error){
           console.error(error); //never ignore errors!
           try {
             //i think error is an Error Object here, so it doesn't have .search function
             if(error.search(/No data returned from the query/im) > 0)    // regex case insensitive search and search multiline as source string is multiline
                res.status(500).send('Invalid Request Match');
             else 
                res.status(500).send('ERROR: '+error);
           } catch (err) {
             console.error(err);
              res.status(500).send('some unknown error');
           };
         });
      });
```

1. Edit: Sorry, removed `.finally` because you may send response twice.
2. Edit, better approach to handle error in `.catch` block.

---

```
//make catch block error safe to make sure no error occurs
if (error && error.message == 'No data returned from the query.') {
  res.status(500).send('Invalid Request Match');
} else {
  res.status(500).send('ERROR: '+error);
}
```

Comment: One typo though, the `catch` you mentioned does not take function and only allows to pass a parameter.

Yes, you have pointed to the right direction that the `error` does not have `.search()`. What should I do in this case if I want to parse the error message string? The error appears in following way on console (in multiline):
`ERROR: QueryResultError {
    code: queryResultErrorCode.noData
    message: "No data returned from the query."
    received: 0
    query: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='hannan@designsoftstudios.com' AND password='1234'"
}`

Comment: Hurrey!! solved the issue as per your directions. Have parse the `error` object to string using `error.toString();` as the `.toString()` is a global method and it worked for me.

Comment: Since your database return proper `QueryResultError`, I think you can make it error safe in the `catch` block. Edited the answer with better approach to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

We use response codes in ExpressJs quite intensively when creating an API service. So it seems a right way that we make use of them directly instead of doing `if-else` in `catch()`.

Hence, the right way would be:

```
.catch(function(error){
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
        res.status(204).send('No Content; Invalid Request Match');
    })
```

However, If you want to display/return detailed message you can do that as well. You can check: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res for details on ways you can response back. You can render an HTML template, or return JSON response or even multiline text.
I don't know why `if-else` creates problem but you can go other way around.

In your specific case the `error` does not have `.search()` method attached to it. So better to parse it to string first using `.toString();`.